# Turn Signal Malfunctioning

Tags: electrical, turn-signal

My left turn signal started malfunctioning the other day, here are the symptoms.

1. left turn signal (on dashboard) clicks at roughly twice the rate as the right turn signal.
2. rear turning light flashes quickly.
3. front turning light does not flash.

I tried replacing the fuse but that did not work. Should I replace the light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way most indicators are set up is that the load on them affects the flash rate (those older models used current flowing through a bi-metallic strip: the bulb current heated the strip which then broke the flow of current).  Modern indicator circuits are often much more electronic, but the same setup is used to make it obvious to the driver what the problem is).

As @NickC says, it's the bulb that needs replacing.

The majority of indicator problems are down to the bulb - it is a consumable - so just replace it.

Less likely is the indicator relay (see [Is it possible to repair an intermittent or flaky turn signal flasher relay?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/26424/is-it-possible-to-repair-an-intermittent-or-flaky-turn-signal-flasher-relay) for a possible repair).

Answer (score 5):

The front light bulb has failed. Simple fix!